# Get $_GET[] from the URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get `$_GET["id"]` from the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //TRAITEMENT ENVOIE INVITATION
    $("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal").bind('click', function f() {
        var afficher_plus_modal = $(this).attr("class");
        $(this).unbind('click', f);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "voir_profil_includes/func_infos.php",
            data: {
                "afficher_plus_modal": afficher_plus_modal,
                //I want to get here $_GET['id']        
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#amis_commun_liste .afficher_plus_modal").html("En cours");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data != "success") {                          
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is it possible to get `$_GET[]` from the URL with jQuery?

Comment: From where do you want to get this `id` GET variable?

Comment: why don't you simply parse url ? or get param values from url ?

Comment: from the url of the current page

Comment: @Usman Rana HOW ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Usage**

```
// query string: ?foo=lorem&bar=&baz
var foo = getParameterByName('foo'); // "lorem"
```

In your code:

```
 data: {
    "afficher_plus_modal": afficher_plus_modal,
    "id": getParameterByName('id')        
 },
```

Just dont forget to define the function beforhand.